# Adding HTML to login page under the body tag

Tags: login

Is anyone aware of means to add html directly under the body tag on the wordpress login page, ideally using functions.php?

I'm aware of the various hooks and filters listed in the codex, but I have a use case which requires a simple line of html be present across the whole site and after several hours of research I'm no further forward.

Answer (score 3):

If you look the **wp-login.php** file, you will see a hook **login_header**. So you add any custom content above the login form. Here is the example:

```
add_action( 'login_header', 'wpse330527_add_html_content' );
function wpse330527_add_html_content() {
?>

ENTER YOUR HTML CODE

<?php
}
```

You will add the code into functions.php file of your active theme.

Answer (score 1):

#### Some notes

You may notice that the `login_init` hook puts the code *immediately* under the body tag, and the `login_header` code is inserted later. Other tags are described in the [documentation, here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Login_Hooks):

- Actions in the **head** of the document: login_enqueue_scripts, login_head.
- Filters in the **body**: login_headerurl, login_headertitle, login_message, login_errors.
- Actions at the bottom of and below the form: login_form, login_footer.

#### The Code:

```php
// define the login_init callback 
function action_login_init( $array ) { ?>
  <h1 class='even-above-login_header'>hi</h1>
<?php }; 
       
// add the action 
add_action( 'login_init', 'action_login_init', 10, 1 );
```

#### The Result:

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="even-above-login_header">hi</h1>
  <!-- etc -->
</body>
```